# Does datastore supports inequality filter?

Tags: go, datastore

I'm trying to run a query using the inequality filter but it errors out:`datastore: invalid operator "!=" in filter "Field1 !="` 
 Isn't this supported?

I'm using Go whose documentation doesn't mention this filter but the [python docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Filters) seem to support negation so I'm wondering if it's a go specific issue or if I'm missing something.

```
q.Query = q.Query.Filter("Field1 !=", value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Property_filters), it states that filter only supports these: `=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`.

So `!=` isn't supported. However you may have a workaround like this:

```
q.Query = q.Query.Filter("Field1 >", value).Filter("Field1 <", value)
```

which should yield the result as `!=`.

Comment: That's really awkward isn't it? Since the python api actually supports it I'm wondering if this is a go sdk bug

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat, yes it *IS* strange and I come from Python background too. I have just started learning Go and found this limitation *VERY* annoying

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat, by the way, shouldn't the query be more like: `datastore.NewQuery(...).Filter()`? I guess this is just a quick code that you try to demonstrate the point.

Comment: I'm actually using a wrapper to make the api less painful  thus the reason why the code looks a bit unusual. I guess I have to add a few more lines to handle the negation filter though the std api limitation doesn't make much sense to me..

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat, I made myself forget what I have already learnt datastore api in Python so the transition to writing code in Go is now rather smooth.